# Iterate through columns performing group_by and neighbor assignment

Tags: r, iteration, tidyverse, spread

Probably this is a common question, but I wasn't able to find any answer capable to fit in my problem.

I have data that has a column where some lines are assigned and others are NA.
The NA cases may be assigned if it belongs to a group where has at least one item assigned.
This data has other columns to use to group, and this column has a hierarchy, it means we should group each column once per time in a specific order which an advantage that these group columns are numeric starting from `1` to `0.2`.
This is a kinda depth-first algorithm I think.

```
structure(list(ID = c("WP_012391491.1/58-334", "WP_045025307.1/57-335", 
"WP_065911868.1/57-334", "WP_094130548.1/57-334", "WP_041093274.1/57-335", 
"WP_087741863.1/58-335", "WP_048735837.1/58-335", "WP_024526760.1/58-335", 
"YP_006375059.1/60-339", "4RK1_A", "WP_081134210.1/58-337", "WP_067481377.1/58-337", 
"WP_023519081.1/58-337", "WP_005918334.1/58-332", "WP_011673819.1/58-332", 
"WP_101874263.1/58-332", "YP_004891129.1/58-332", "WP_021730312.1/58-332", 
"WP_105451130.1/58-332", "WP_105448628.1/58-332", "4RK0_A", "NP_816580.1/58-331", 
"WP_014215863.1/58-333", "WP_014074009.1/57-334", "WP_014939645.1/57-334", 
"WP_057909529.1/57-334", "WP_035168530.1/57-335", "YP_001328142.1/20-321", 
"NP_386672.1/20-321", "NP_437689.1/21-322", "WP_064322056.1/23-326", 
"WP_095444766.1/23-326", "WP_022561933.1/19-321", "WP_060691636.1/22-324", 
"WP_062000852.1/16-317", "4RY9_A", "WP_011809835.1/29-330", "WP_067873970.1/47-338", 
"WP_067195222.1/48-334", "WP_108390182.1/48-337", "WP_088455092.1/48-337", 
"WP_013585042.1/48-336", "WP_094181221.1/110-393", "WP_013118380.1/59-348", 
"WP_078845346.1/48-338", "WP_058920843.1/26-338", "WP_020937919.1/34-340", 
"WP_029381425.1/47-337", "WP_013152136.1/51-349", "WP_079255911.1/49-343", 
"WP_078638163.1/49-341", "WP_064731434.1/47-343", "WP_031033051.1/49-344", 
"WP_095681865.1/49-343", "WP_079255907.1/54-335", "WP_077275989.1/55-331", 
"WP_071455952.1/54-331", "WP_068799469.1/44-336", "WP_108392182.1/49-339", 
"WP_012865347.1/56-345", "WP_014104198.1/48-350", "WP_007397977.1/51-337", 
"WP_087607280.1/49-337", "WP_028700814.1/24-338", "WP_028700389.1/48-340", 
"NP_350138.1/55-335", "3G85_A"), PDB = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE), ligandId = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "CL MSE RIB", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "RIB", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GOL TLZ", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GOL MSE"), `1` = c(138240, 
50687, 1378, 126023, 237469, 124229, 41453, 217657, 91126, 183150, 
107179, 6274, 262561, 176386, 148744, 74195, 93951, 264634, 95933, 
96095, 183149, 188356, 250907, 252918, 243804, 66122, 207410, 
87437, 181530, 187508, 16752, 81323, 265938, 58828, 13021, 638, 
638, 28566, 4878, 89140, 122445, 155228, 125955, 164812, 120428, 
55374, 257779, 219988, 170251, 116415, 120125, 14694, 208562, 
78746, 116429, 115371, 21301, 27608, 88975, 166418, 252468, 197645, 
123797, 220728, 220653, 182317, 183297), `0.9` = c(115828, 171070, 
47923, 71525, 156529, 98825, 165289, 189247, 31455, 31455, 88210, 
61492, 196793, 131804, 143158, 10327, 10327, 10327, 26521, 26521, 
31058, 31058, 123582, 121348, 186492, 34988, 162176, 25258, 25258, 
138442, 15902, 15902, 196359, 62175, 46251, 147381, 147381, 56135, 
59451, 76614, 102076, 130255, 71453, 114643, 96504, 58676, 197451, 
192775, 114280, 23991, 23991, 53944, 190660, 69970, 97189, 94703, 
43808, 33373, 76685, 111928, 125148, 137147, 98782, 193109, 193143, 
26538, 26538), `0.8` = c(110007, 126908, 41980, 81956, 146463, 
7523, 7523, 7523, 13169, 13169, 13169, 54211, 144263, 30337, 
144486, 68026, 68026, 68026, 69168, 69168, 67041, 67041, 93235, 
93313, 91652, 132429, 139245, 64638, 64638, 62222, 81172, 81172, 
141549, 44105, 47435, 96620, 96620, 54519, 55356, 70400, 84802, 
119491, 82179, 108083, 39098, 131355, 142185, 137368, 106528, 
8338, 8338, 8338, 8338, 83518, 39373, 26484, 28621, 51215, 70429, 
105638, 23426, 23426, 85745, 137611, 137684, 57248, 57248), `0.7` = c(67870, 
102232, 35151, 42345, 92357, 99040, 99040, 99040, 6533, 6533, 
6533, 6533, 6533, 20017, 20017, 47416, 47416, 47416, 48130, 48130, 
82070, 82070, 73319, 73626, 7056, 7056, 7056, 46979, 46979, 81437, 
13586, 13586, 13586, 27032, 26586, 85055, 85055, 13402, 13402, 
15242, 15242, 77617, 42498, 67680, 6951, 6951, 6951, 112867, 
67415, 12983, 12983, 12983, 12983, 12983, 54691, 23945, 25470, 
33887, 49979, 65311, 19335, 19335, 19335, 113208, 113217, 81718, 
81718), `0.6` = c(8366, 8366, 23618, 32642, 70323, 78974, 78974, 
78974, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 
1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 56028, 56694, 83944, 83944, 83944, 
11860, 11860, 11860, 15130, 15130, 15130, 15130, 25412, 64954, 
64954, 24654, 24654, 38268, 38268, 59264, 32603, 51690, 10955, 
10955, 10955, 10955, 50901, 18836, 18836, 18836, 18836, 18836, 
42361, 6461, 6461, 28216, 38284, 50584, 61467, 61467, 61467, 
11132, 11132, 62398, 62398), `0.5` = c(568, 568, 568, 568, 568, 
568, 568, 568, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 
28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 43941, 44445, 
66203, 66203, 66203, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 
1080, 1080, 1080, 3884, 3884, 3884, 3884, 3884, 4264, 4264, 8047, 
8047, 8047, 8047, 8047, 14712, 14712, 14712, 14712, 14712, 15093, 
15671, 15671, 21991, 29850, 39515, 48308, 48308, 48308, 68304, 
68304, 48996, 48996), `0.4` = c(2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 
2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 
2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 
809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 
809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 
809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 13941, 
13941), `0.3` = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 
1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 
1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 
1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 
1962, 1962), `0.2` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -67L))
```

or

To handle this problem I wrote a function and call it a lot of times.

What I'd like to do this without calling it a lot of time and if possible without the need to write a function.

My solution works but spends a long time processing.

```
assingn_lig <- function(data, group_col){
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!rlang::ensym(group_col)) %>%
    mutate( 
      ligandId = case_when(
        PDB == TRUE ~ ligandId ,
        !is.na(ligandId) ~ ligandId ,
        any( PDB == T ) & is.na(ligandId) ~ paste(unique(unlist(str_split(na.omit(ligandId), " ")) ), collapse = " "),
        TRUE ~ NA_character_  
      )
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
}

tmp2 %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `1`) %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `0.9`) %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `0.8`) %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `0.7`) %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `0.6`) %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `0.5`) %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `0.4`) %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `0.3`) %>%
  assingn_lig(group_col = `0.2`)
```

So, does anyone knows a better strategy?

This is the output:

```
# A tibble: 67 x 12
   ID                    PDB   ligandId      `1`  `0.9`  `0.8`  `0.7` `0.6` `0.5` `0.4` `0.3` `0.2`
   <chr>                 <lgl> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 WP_012391491.1/58-334 FALSE CL MSE RIB 138240 115828 110007  67870  8366   568  2884     9     1
 2 WP_045025307.1/57-335 FALSE CL MSE RIB  50687 171070 126908 102232  8366   568  2884     9     1
 3 WP_065911868.1/57-334 FALSE CL MSE RIB   1378  47923  41980  35151 23618   568  2884     9     1
 4 WP_094130548.1/57-334 FALSE CL MSE RIB 126023  71525  81956  42345 32642   568  2884     9     1
 5 WP_041093274.1/57-335 FALSE CL MSE RIB 237469 156529 146463  92357 70323   568  2884     9     1
 6 WP_087741863.1/58-335 FALSE CL MSE RIB 124229  98825   7523  99040 78974   568  2884     9     1
 7 WP_048735837.1/58-335 FALSE CL MSE RIB  41453 165289   7523  99040 78974   568  2884     9     1
 8 WP_024526760.1/58-335 FALSE CL MSE RIB 217657 189247   7523  99040 78974   568  2884     9     1
 9 YP_006375059.1/60-339 FALSE CL MSE RIB  91126  31455  13169   6533  1269 28283  2884     9     1
10 4RK1_A                TRUE  CL MSE RIB 183150  31455  13169   6533  1269 28283  2884     9     1
# ? with 57 more rows
> dput(tmp1)
structure(list(ID = c("WP_012391491.1/58-334", "WP_045025307.1/57-335", 
"WP_065911868.1/57-334", "WP_094130548.1/57-334", "WP_041093274.1/57-335", 
"WP_087741863.1/58-335", "WP_048735837.1/58-335", "WP_024526760.1/58-335", 
"YP_006375059.1/60-339", "4RK1_A", "WP_081134210.1/58-337", "WP_067481377.1/58-337", 
"WP_023519081.1/58-337", "WP_005918334.1/58-332", "WP_011673819.1/58-332", 
"WP_101874263.1/58-332", "YP_004891129.1/58-332", "WP_021730312.1/58-332", 
"WP_105451130.1/58-332", "WP_105448628.1/58-332", "4RK0_A", "NP_816580.1/58-331", 
"WP_014215863.1/58-333", "WP_014074009.1/57-334", "WP_014939645.1/57-334", 
"WP_057909529.1/57-334", "WP_035168530.1/57-335", "YP_001328142.1/20-321", 
"NP_386672.1/20-321", "NP_437689.1/21-322", "WP_064322056.1/23-326", 
"WP_095444766.1/23-326", "WP_022561933.1/19-321", "WP_060691636.1/22-324", 
"WP_062000852.1/16-317", "4RY9_A", "WP_011809835.1/29-330", "WP_067873970.1/47-338", 
"WP_067195222.1/48-334", "WP_108390182.1/48-337", "WP_088455092.1/48-337", 
"WP_013585042.1/48-336", "WP_094181221.1/110-393", "WP_013118380.1/59-348", 
"WP_078845346.1/48-338", "WP_058920843.1/26-338", "WP_020937919.1/34-340", 
"WP_029381425.1/47-337", "WP_013152136.1/51-349", "WP_079255911.1/49-343", 
"WP_078638163.1/49-341", "WP_064731434.1/47-343", "WP_031033051.1/49-344", 
"WP_095681865.1/49-343", "WP_079255907.1/54-335", "WP_077275989.1/55-331", 
"WP_071455952.1/54-331", "WP_068799469.1/44-336", "WP_108392182.1/49-339", 
"WP_012865347.1/56-345", "WP_014104198.1/48-350", "WP_007397977.1/51-337", 
"WP_087607280.1/49-337", "WP_028700814.1/24-338", "WP_028700389.1/48-340", 
"NP_350138.1/55-335", "3G85_A"), PDB = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE), ligandId = c("CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", 
"CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", 
"CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", 
"CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", 
"CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "RIB", "RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", 
"CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "CL MSE RIB", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", 
"GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", 
"GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", 
"GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", 
"GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", 
"GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", 
"GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", "GOL TLZ", 
"GOL MSE", "GOL MSE"), `1` = c(138240, 50687, 1378, 126023, 237469, 
124229, 41453, 217657, 91126, 183150, 107179, 6274, 262561, 176386, 
148744, 74195, 93951, 264634, 95933, 96095, 183149, 188356, 250907, 
252918, 243804, 66122, 207410, 87437, 181530, 187508, 16752, 
81323, 265938, 58828, 13021, 638, 638, 28566, 4878, 89140, 122445, 
155228, 125955, 164812, 120428, 55374, 257779, 219988, 170251, 
116415, 120125, 14694, 208562, 78746, 116429, 115371, 21301, 
27608, 88975, 166418, 252468, 197645, 123797, 220728, 220653, 
182317, 183297), `0.9` = c(115828, 171070, 47923, 71525, 156529, 
98825, 165289, 189247, 31455, 31455, 88210, 61492, 196793, 131804, 
143158, 10327, 10327, 10327, 26521, 26521, 31058, 31058, 123582, 
121348, 186492, 34988, 162176, 25258, 25258, 138442, 15902, 15902, 
196359, 62175, 46251, 147381, 147381, 56135, 59451, 76614, 102076, 
130255, 71453, 114643, 96504, 58676, 197451, 192775, 114280, 
23991, 23991, 53944, 190660, 69970, 97189, 94703, 43808, 33373, 
76685, 111928, 125148, 137147, 98782, 193109, 193143, 26538, 
26538), `0.8` = c(110007, 126908, 41980, 81956, 146463, 7523, 
7523, 7523, 13169, 13169, 13169, 54211, 144263, 30337, 144486, 
68026, 68026, 68026, 69168, 69168, 67041, 67041, 93235, 93313, 
91652, 132429, 139245, 64638, 64638, 62222, 81172, 81172, 141549, 
44105, 47435, 96620, 96620, 54519, 55356, 70400, 84802, 119491, 
82179, 108083, 39098, 131355, 142185, 137368, 106528, 8338, 8338, 
8338, 8338, 83518, 39373, 26484, 28621, 51215, 70429, 105638, 
23426, 23426, 85745, 137611, 137684, 57248, 57248), `0.7` = c(67870, 
102232, 35151, 42345, 92357, 99040, 99040, 99040, 6533, 6533, 
6533, 6533, 6533, 20017, 20017, 47416, 47416, 47416, 48130, 48130, 
82070, 82070, 73319, 73626, 7056, 7056, 7056, 46979, 46979, 81437, 
13586, 13586, 13586, 27032, 26586, 85055, 85055, 13402, 13402, 
15242, 15242, 77617, 42498, 67680, 6951, 6951, 6951, 112867, 
67415, 12983, 12983, 12983, 12983, 12983, 54691, 23945, 25470, 
33887, 49979, 65311, 19335, 19335, 19335, 113208, 113217, 81718, 
81718), `0.6` = c(8366, 8366, 23618, 32642, 70323, 78974, 78974, 
78974, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 
1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 1269, 56028, 56694, 83944, 83944, 83944, 
11860, 11860, 11860, 15130, 15130, 15130, 15130, 25412, 64954, 
64954, 24654, 24654, 38268, 38268, 59264, 32603, 51690, 10955, 
10955, 10955, 10955, 50901, 18836, 18836, 18836, 18836, 18836, 
42361, 6461, 6461, 28216, 38284, 50584, 61467, 61467, 61467, 
11132, 11132, 62398, 62398), `0.5` = c(568, 568, 568, 568, 568, 
568, 568, 568, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 
28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 28283, 43941, 44445, 
66203, 66203, 66203, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 
1080, 1080, 1080, 3884, 3884, 3884, 3884, 3884, 4264, 4264, 8047, 
8047, 8047, 8047, 8047, 14712, 14712, 14712, 14712, 14712, 15093, 
15671, 15671, 21991, 29850, 39515, 48308, 48308, 48308, 68304, 
68304, 48996, 48996), `0.4` = c(2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 
2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 
2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 2884, 
809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 
809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 
809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 809, 13941, 
13941), `0.3` = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 
1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 
1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 
1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 1561, 
1962, 1962), `0.2` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -67L))
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here for example, If I run `df %>%
  group_by(\`1\`) %>%
  mutate( 
    ligandId = case_when(
      PDB == TRUE ~ ligandId ,
      !is.na(ligandId) ~ ligandId ,
      any(PDB == T) & is.na(ligandId) ~ paste(na.omit(unique(ligandId)), collapse = " "),
      TRUE ~ NA_character_  
    )` nothing is changed since there is only 1 value in each group?

Comment: @RonakShah I add a more useful example, I'd like to add a link to the data, but it is very large and I cannot.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a value to `ligandId` based on common grouping in the hierarchy (like 1, first then 0.9, then 0.8, etc.)?

Comment: @akash87 exactly. It is assigned only if it hasn't any `ligandId` and if it has at least one assigned in a group.

Comment: hi, please, can you add expected output?

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini was added, remembering that my code are working. S